# Get Running Difference of Dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a list of multiple dates in mongo and I want to find the time difference in between each one (e.g. How much time between objectId 3 and 4, objectId 4 and 5, objectId 5 and 6. I tried mongo's $subtract, but it gave me the answer in milliseconds, which when converted doesn't make sense. Also, there shouldn't be a dateDiff value for objectId 3 because there is no date coming before it.

```
> db.collection.find({item:"1"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "item" : "1", "date" : ISODate("2016-02-08T10:24:36Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4"), "item" : "1", "date" : ISODate("2016-02-13T10:24:36Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5"), "item" : "1", "date" : ISODate("2016-02-29T10:24:36Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6"), "item" : "1", "date" : ISODate("2016-03-13T10:24:36Z") }

> db.collection.aggregate([
   {$match:{item:"1"}},
   {$sort:{date:1}},
   {$project:{dateDiff:{$subtract:[new Date(),"$date"]}}}
])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "dateDiff" : NumberLong("18412790289") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4"), "dateDiff" : NumberLong("17980790289") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5"), "dateDiff" : NumberLong("16598390289") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6"), "dateDiff" : NumberLong("15302390289") }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look at the statement you attempted and understand that all you asked the "database server" to do was *"subract the date value from the **current time right now**"*, which is what `new Date()` is actually doing. This explains the output you get from your attempt, since that value is not the *"previous document date"*.

If all you are after is the difference in date between each preceding item and the current then I really do not think this is a task for the "database server" to perform in itself. What you are asking, is more naturally addressed by simply processing the cursor and keeping a reference to the previous "date" then simply subtracting that from the current:

```
var previousDate = false;
db.getCollection('collection').find().sort({ "item": 1, "date": 1 }).map( d => {
  var diff = (previousDate) ? NumberLong(d.date - previousDate) : 0;
  previousDate = d.date;
  return Object.assign(d,{ diff })
})
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598b794c1b61b8b7a12329b4"),
    "item" : "1",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-02-08T10:24:36.000Z"),
    "diff" : 0.0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598b794c1b61b8b7a12329b5"),
    "item" : "1",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-02-13T10:24:36.000Z"),
    "diff" : NumberLong(432000000)
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598b794c1b61b8b7a12329b6"),
    "item" : "1",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-02-29T10:24:36.000Z"),
    "diff" : NumberLong(1382400000)
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598b794c1b61b8b7a12329b7"),
    "item" : "1",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-03-13T10:24:36.000Z"),
    "diff" : NumberLong(1123200000)
}
```

This is generally the best thing to do since the natural occurrences are *"one following the other"* and that is what processing a cursor actually does. MongoDB itself has no real way of *"referring to the value of a previous document"* and the only way to do that is essentially by coercing the values into an "array" for processing.

So in most real world cases such processing "as an array" is not actually practical and would in fact exceed the 16MB BSON limit by storing the values in an array of any significant size.

If however you feel you must do that "on the server", then the most efficient usage is by applying [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) which has access to the "current" and "previous reduced" items when processing the list as `$$this` and `$$value` respectively:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "item": 1, "date": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$item",
    "diff": { "$push": "$date" }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "diff": {
      "$map": {
        "input": {
          "$reduce": {
            "input": "$diff",
            "initialValue": [],
            "in": {
              "$concatArrays": [
                "$$value",
                [{ 
                  "date": "$$this", 
                  "diff": { 
                    "$cond": {
                      "if": { "$eq": [{ "$size": "$$value" }, 0] },
                      "then": 0,
                      "else": {
                        "$subtract": ["$$this", { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$value.date", -1] }]    
                      }
                    }   
                  }
                }]
              ]  
            }
          }
        },
        "as": "d",
        "in": "$$d.diff"
      }  
    }  
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$diff" }
])
```

Which outputs

```
{ "_id" : "1", "diff" : 0.0 }
{ "_id" : "1", "diff" : NumberLong(432000000) }
{ "_id" : "1", "diff" : NumberLong(1382400000) }
{ "_id" : "1", "diff" : NumberLong(1123200000) }
```

Note that since [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) like it's other language counterparts is generally about "reducing" a result, we make the returned result an array by using [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) to "join" the "previous" and "current" output.

The basic process on each item ( aside from logic for the first item ) is to [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) the previous result through [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) using the index `-1` which means the "last" item of the array, from the "current" item being processed from what was collected via the previous [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/).

Since the "previous date" is needed, the [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) output includes the `"date"` value in order to determine the difference between each. The actual `"diff"` values are then extracted by the wrapping [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operation, which only returns the values for that property, and comes to the final result where then the array is processed with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in order to put the items back into document form.

Less pipeline stages always means better performance, as every stage is essentially a "pass through the data" and that takes time. So here the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) does "collection" and the next stage finds the "difference". That's essentially the operation and it really takes just those two stages.

It's a bit of "juggling" but a lot less than you can potentially do and would be the most performant way to actually tackle "on the server". But this really is not a "server" problem, and is far better suited to simply "processing the cursor in sequence" just as is shown initially.

Answer (score 2):

Using new `Date()` you are effectively comparing the **current** date to what's in your respective date field. What you want to do is compare the values in the different documents to each other which can be achieved by creating some helper array(s) with all dates in them.

Here is a commented version that works:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        item: "1" // not really needed but I guess it makes sense in your specific case so I leave it here
    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        date: 1 // we need to sort in order to find the next bigger date
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$item", // for every item...
        "date": { $push: "$date" }, // ...we create two identical arrays (could be done using another $project stage, too)
        "allDates": { $push: "$date" } // ...that each contain all dates that we find for our item
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$date" // this will flatten one of the two created date arrays
},
{
    $project: {
        "date": 1,
        "followingDate": {
            $arrayElemAt: [
                "$allDates", // here we use the second (remaining) date array to find the next date...
                { $add: [ { $indexOfArray: [ "$allDates", "$date" ] }, 1 ] } // ...which needs to sit in that sorted array at the position of the element we're looking at right now + 1
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    // now, we simply create a nice result document with various ways of looking at the date differences
    $project: {
        "date": 1,
        "followingDate": 1,
        "differenceInMilliseconds": {
            $subtract: [ "$followingDate", "$date" ]
        },
        "differenceInSeconds": {
            $divide: [ { $subtract: [ "$followingDate", "$date" ] }, 1000 ]
        },
        "differenceInMinutes": {
            $divide: [ { $subtract: [ "$followingDate", "$date" ] }, 1000 * 60 ]
        },
        "differenceInHours": {
            $divide: [ { $subtract: [ "$followingDate", "$date" ] }, 1000 * 60 * 60 ]
        },
        "differenceInDays": {
            $divide: [ { $subtract: [ "$followingDate", "$date" ] }, 1000 * 60 * 60 *24 ]
        }
    }
}])
```